# Unable to insert a form's ID in the "("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function())" statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I came across this code from one of your questions and I would like to use this for what I am doing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selected = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
       selected.push($(this).val());
  });

});

</script>
```

I would like to use a form's id in the place of `input:checkbox[name=type]` so that I can extract the values of all checked check-boxes in that form.

How can I possibly do that?

Comment: If you're using an ID selector, the `each` becomes irrelevent as IDs should be unique. You'd be better off putting a class on each of the checkboxes in your form and using a selector for those. Can you post the HTML you have.

Comment: I think we are using ID selector.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly then you just need to add the form ID to the start of the selector:

```
$("#yourForm input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
});
```

This will now match all checked checkboxes that are descendants of `#yourForm`.

Comment: @ArvinthShriram - I left it there because you had it in your question! It will select any checkbox whose `name` attribute has the value "type". You can just get rid of it if you want to select all checked checkboxes.

Comment: I dont understand what they mean by [name=type]. why is it specified?

Comment: I get it. Ok I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: Changing name=type worked. But I am not getting the desirable thing. Will post that as a separate question with my code. Thanks for helping guys.